# Mocha Uncaught Error for catch exceptions

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, travis-ci

I am trying to write test cases for the below code:

```
async readFile(filename) {
    try {
      const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
      const rs = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.message;
    }
}
```

test case:

```
await expect(readFile('invalid-file.txt')).to.be.rejectedWith(
        "ENOENT, no such file or directory 'invalid-file.txt'",
      );
```

I am getting error for the above test case:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'invalid-file.txt'
      at Binding.<anonymous> (node_modules/mock-fs/lib/binding.js:383:15)
```

How to write test case for catch exceptions?

Note: This test is passing in my local, but failing in Travis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `eventually`: `expect(readFile('invalid-file.txt')).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is also not working. What I observed was these tests are passing in my local but failing in travis.